# É possível esconder um método publico da classe abstrata?

Tags: c#, método, classes-abstratas

Tenho o seguinte cenário:

```
public abstract class ClasseA
{
    public string[] MetodoC(string parametro, string nomeObjeto)
    {
        // ações metodo
    }        
}

public class ClasseB : ClasseA
{
    public string[] MetodoD(string nomeObjeto)
    {
        string[] Resultado;
        string Parametros = "";
        Parametros = "asdfg..." // parametros 

        Resultado = MetodoC(Parametros, nomeObjeto); 

        return Resultado;
    }

    public string[] MetodoE(string nomeObjeto)
    {
        string[] Resultado;
        string Parametros = "";
        Parametros = "12345..." // parametros 

        Resultado = MetodoC(Parametros, nomeObjeto); 

        return Resultado;
    }
}
```

Quando eu instancio a `ClasseB`, ela apresenta dos métodos `MetodoC(...)`, `MetodoD(...)` e `MetodoE(...)`.

Existe uma maneira de apresentar apenas os métodos `MetodoD(...)` e `MetodoE(...)`?

Eu gostaria que o `MetodoC(...)` ficasse "escondido".

Comment: Escondidos pra quem? Pra outras classes? Pras classes derivadas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ao invés de utilizar o modificador de acesso `public`, utilize `protected`.

Um método `protected` da ClasseA terá sua visibilidade limitada as classes que a herdam, ou seja, dentro da ClasseB, mas quem instanciar a ClasseB não terá visibilidade do método.